# Proper way to export a .net web application (website) and how to fix this error with loaded a presumably improperly exported site

Tags: .net

I've inherited a website that was built in .net. I've done very little work in javascript, c# ... etc. I've installed visual studio and installed the web ... plugin or whatever. My problem is, when I attempt to open the project file (which I copied over from the live IIS directory) I get an error indicating:

```
C:\program files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets 
was not found, confirm the path of the import declaration ....
```

In a normal situation, I assume this is where you would export the project. In python i'm pretty consistent with making sure I use virtual environments.  What is the appropriate way to export a .net project and is there anything I can do to bypass or fix this error message?

When i check that path location - i have

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0
```

and not v15.0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are attempting to import a project that was written in Visual Studio 2017 using Visual Studio 2012. Try downloading the correct version of VS and use that to open the project.